# El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo .JsonResult, pero este diccionario requiere IEnumerable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente código el cual hace una consulta a mi bd y muestra los datos en una tabla html:

```html
public JsonResult DataJson()
{
   List<MyClass> data = bd.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("Select * from mytabla").ToList();
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

MyClass

```html
public class MyClass
    {
        public int Usuario  { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int Semanas { get; set; }
        public double Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string Concepto { get; set; }
        public int Semana { get; set; }
     }
```

Y con ajax los recibo y muestro los resultados en mi vista:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
    Fill_tabla();
    });
    
    function Fill_tabla() {
    $.getJSON("/MyController/DataJson", function (data)     {
     $.each(data, function (idx, opt) {
     $('#datatable').append('<tr><td>' + opt.column1 + '</td><td>' + opt.column2 + '</td></tr>');
            });
        }, 'json');
    }
</script>
```

Ahora el siguiente código envía un array con los datos de mi tabla HTML al controlador para actualizarlos en la base de datos hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que muestra el error:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo .JsonResult,
>   pero este diccionario requiere IEnumerable.

Se supone que debo convertir el array a IEnumerable? o como?

Aclaro que ambas funciones (ajax y la de del controlador) se repiten por cada fila de mi tabla.

```html
 function GuardarF() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/MyController/MyView',
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                  array: array
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.rstProceso === "true") {
                    console.log('Exito: ' + data.rstMensaje);
                } else if (data.rstProceso === "false") {
                    console.log('Algo salió mal ' + data.rstMensaje);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, err){
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(int[] array)
{
  JsonResult dtaEjecucionTarea = default(JsonResult);
       
        if (Update_MyView(array))
        {
            dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new
            {
                rstProceso = "true",
                MessageGestion = "Cambios guardados con éxito"
            });
        }
        else
        { 
            dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new
            {
                rstProceso = "false",
                MessageGestion = "Error, algo salió mal, intente de nuevo"
            });
        }
  return View(dtaEjecucionTarea);
}

public bool Update_MyView(int[] array)
{
   if (array != null)
   {
    //my code
    bd.SaveChanges();
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Mi Modelo

```html
public partial class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Usuario { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Semanas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string Concepto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Semana { get; set; }
    }
```

Mensaje de error en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De donde sacas el elemento `array` que envías en `data: { array: array }` ?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta  con una funcion recojo los elementos de las filas de la tabla y los meto a un var array = [];, ese lo envio al controller (hasta ahi todo bien)

Comment: Entonces donde está el problema, no lo entiendo muy bien..

Comment: @RafaelAcosta El problema es que muestra el error: "El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo .JsonResult, pero este diccionario requiere IEnumerable" en la parte: error: function (jqXHR, status, err){
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas en lo que devuelves en el método, estás pasando un JSONResult como parámetro a tu vista (MyView.cshtml)

```
JsonResult dtaEjecucionTarea = default(JsonResult);
...
return View(dtaEjecucionTarea);
```

Cuando haces return sin indicar un nombre de vista, el sistema entiende que la vista la cual tiene que coger es la que se llame de igual modo que el método que estás ejecutando en el controlador, en este caso "MyView.cshmtl"

Tienes que revisar en tu vista, cuando indicas el modelo que usa, que clase es y pasarle esa clase.

```
@model MiClase
```

El error es ese, tu vista espera un objeto de una clase en concreto pero tu le estás pasando un JSONResult

Si lo que quieres es devolver directamente lo que estás rellenando en el if:

```
dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new
            {
                rstProceso = "true",
                MessageGestion = "Cambios guardados con éxito"
            });
```

Tu return tiene que ser así

```
return Json( new {
                rstProceso = "true",
                MessageGestion = "Cambios guardados con éxito"
            } );
```

O en tu caso:

```
return dtaEjecucionTarea;
```

Comment: Justamente era eso, muchas gracias :)